# Properties for a matrix invariant under rotation (3D)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations

What $3 \times 3$ matrix would be invariant under any rotation?

i.e. $AR=RA$, where $R$ is the rotation matrix.

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret "R is **the** rotation matrix..If you mean the specific matrix $R$ then your condition means the matrices commute so they can be, for example, rotations about the same axis...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** See what you can extract from that condition when $R$ belongs to the set:$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\-1&0&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\0&1&0\\-1&0&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&-1\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}\right\}.$$

Comment: I got $a_(21)=-a_(12), a_(11) = a_(22), a_(13) = a_(23) = a_(31) = a_(32) =0$

Comment: @user3636673 Yes, that's you get from using the first matrix. Now, if you use also the second one, what do you get?

Comment: I got that the result  must be a matrix full of zeros, is this correct?

Comment: @user3636673 It's not. It must be a matrix of the type $\lambda\operatorname{Id}$.